# Sub-population of large dataset based on multiple criteria

Tags: sampling

I am looking to extract example cases of a large dataset. Each entry in my table has multiple columns with essential information describing the entry. I need a random sample of *x* cases covering every criterion independently.

An example would be the following:

```
family     len    fam  res    neff
PF09143    206    d    2.0    100
PF08327    184    d    1.45   2
PF09149    141    b    1.86   1021
PF09148    148    b    1.75   444
PF11447    175    d    1.6    56
PF16647    175    a    2.3    63
```

I need to randomly subsample this set to cover each full range in each of the four columns `len`, `fam`, `res` and `neff`.

First of all, is anything like this even possible? If so, how could this be achieved in theory (can be brief)? Is there any coding package available to do this (i.e function or module)?

---

### Edit 1

In response to @SteveSamuels' comment:

- Size of the data set: **700**
- Size of sample: **30**; 10 from `fam` *a*, *b*, *(c & d)*. Neither are close to one another. *a* contains 130 cases, *b* contains 171, and *(c & d)* contains 391.
- `len` is numeric and can be any number between **60** and **250**.
- `res` is numeric and can be any number between **0.7** and **2.3**.
- `neff` is numberic and can be any number between **0** and **1287** but only a single observation is found between 631 and 1287.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "representative"? (I use the term all the time, but it's a bit hand-wavy.) If you take a random sample of your cases, why wouldn't that be representative by definition?

Comment: What do you mean by "represent"? (Please don't use the term in your definition of it.)

Comment: Any random sample can be considered an example of your population. In your case, I gather your complete dataset is being thought of as a population, so a simple random sample would be an example -> would be representative.

Comment: But to my understanding a simple random sample just picks a sub population completely randomly. It does not consider the different variables and their spread. Right?

Comment: @Felix_Sim  You are correct.  A  simple random sample will have uneven coverage of variable ranges and some portions might not be represented.

Comment: Needed information:  What is the size of the data set?  What are  the constraints, if any,  on the size of the sample you want to draw?

The  Family attributes, are clearly categorical. How many categories?  Are the categories ordered? (so, e.g. "a" & "b" are closer together than "a" & "d"). What about the "len" and "Res" variables? Are these numeric?  What is the range of each? Are there portions of the range in which there are no observations? Have you an idea of the number of distinct values of each?

Comment: The range of a variable in a random sample may not equal the range of the variable in the population. This is certainly true, & well understood. That does not necessarily mean there is any problem w/ random sampling as a process to get a representation of a population. @SteveSamuels knows a lot more about survey sampling than I do, so I'll let him take over from here.

Comment: @SteveSamuels Please see the edit in my post for some extra information

Comment: Thanks; that's very useful.  How many cases are there in  each of the *fam* categories?

Comment: @SteveSamuels Please see Edit1. I've added the numbers to the `fam` bulletpoint.

Comment: What are the pairwise correlations of the three numeric criterion within each level of `fam`? I'm concerned, for example, that if you  high observations in `len`  observations in `neff` will  also be high (or low).  You can do the pairwise plots and just give a rough impression of what you see.

Comment: @SteveSamuels Looking at the plots I would say there are no correlations between any of the observations within each level of `fam`.

Comment: Thanks. One final question (I think): what are the ranges of `len`, `res`, and `neff` in each of the three `fam` levels?

Comment: Never mind, I don't need that information to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend two approaches from the sampling literature that implicitly or explicitly stratify on multiple criteria.

1. Hierarchic Serpentine listing of the population in criterion order, followed by a systematic sampling. This is implicit stratification. For lack of an effective algorithm for serpentine ordering of criterion combinations, I categorize each into four ordered zones and show the listing for those.
2. Random triple lattices  explicitly balance on multiple categorical criteria. To use these,  the numeric criteria are each divided into three zones. Software can possibly be found to construct these in Design of Experiments packages.  However for such a small sample, the lattices are easy to construct by hand.

**Notation**:  I refer to the three criteria `len`, `res`, and `neff` as A, B, and C, respectively.  Categories of `fam` are *sampling strata*, because a separate sample is taken in each.

Each procedure will select combinations of ABC zones, e.g. $132$ means A = 1, B =3, C = 2. The actual data items will be drawn by a simple random sample of size one from each selected combination.

1. Hierarchic Serpentine ordering

Hierarchic Serpentine ordering was formally defined by Williams and Chromy (1980).
Williams, Rick L, and James R Chromy. 1980. SAS sample selection macros. Proceedings of the Fifth Annual SAS Users Group International Conference 5, 392-396.
http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI80/Sugi-80-71%20Williams%20Chromy.pdf
I believe that survey samplers had used the method earlier for two-way geographic stratification

In hierarchic serpentine ordering , the list is first sorted by A, then within levels of A, by ascending then descending levels of B; within levels of B, by ascending then descending levels of C.

It's easier to see the logic for two criteria A and B, which represent geographic longitude and latitude. See also Figures 2 & 3 on p. 395 of the Williams-Chromy article.

A conventional nested ordering, sort on ascending A, then in each A category on ascending B, is shown below. Notice that point (A = 1, B = 4) is followed by (A = 2 B = 1). The two points are not neighbors, being at opposite ends of the B range.

```
 Nested Ordering

                 B
 A=1   1->----------------4

 A=2   1->----------------4

 A=3   1->----------------4

 A=4   1->----------------4
```

In contrast, hierarchic serpentine ordering  alternates ascending and descending sorts.  Here the point (A = 1, B =4) is followed by (A = 2, B = 4), which is a geographic neighbor.

```
  Hierarchic Serpentine ordering
                 B
 A=1   1->----------------4
                          |
 A=2   1----------------<-4
       |
 A=3   1->----------------4
                          |
 A=4   1----------------<-4
```

As stated above, I group each of A,B, and C into four zones.

As an example of creating the zones: the range of `len` is  191 units (250-60 +1). 191/4 =47.75, so make the zone lengths 47 or 48 units (exact equality doesn't matter)

Once each of A, B, and C has been subdivided into four zones each, there will be $4^3=64$ possible combinations.

For each stratum, create a reduced data set containing one observation per ABC zone combination. Only the ABC values are needed.

```
      Hierarchic serpentine ordering 64 ABC combinations. 

      111 112 113 114
      124 123 122 121
      131 132 133 134
      144 143 142 141
      241 242 243 244
      234 233 232 231
      221 222 223 224
      214 213 212 211
      311 312 313 314
      324 323 322 321
      331 332 333 334
      344 343 342 341
      441 442 443 444
      434 433 432 431
      421 422 423 424
      414 413 412 411
```

It's possible that some combinations will not be present in the data and these must be removed "by hand" before taking the stratified sample. As an illustration, suppose that combinations 143 212 and 443 are missing. There will be 64-3= 61 elements. We require a systematic sample of n = 10 and will choose a 1 in 6 sampling fraction. For easy drawing of the systematic sample of 10, we reduce this to 60 elements by removing the "222" element, which is right in the middle.

```
      Hierarchic Serpentine ordering
      after removal of four combinations

      111 112 113 114
      124 123 122 121
      131 132 133 134
      144 142 141
      241 242 243 244
      234 233 232 231
      221 223 224
      214 213 211
      311 312 313 314
      324 323 322 321
      331 332 333 334
      344 343 342 341
      441 442 444
      434 433 432 431
      421 422 423 424
      414 413 412 411
```

I chose a random number between 1 & 6: 4.  The first combination to sample is the 4th, with the others obtained by adding 6 to the previous selection. Here the selections are 4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58. It's easy to pick these by hand, counting by 6 from each previously selected element (easier if all the combinations are listed in long format).

```
 Sort order    Combination
  4              114
 10              132
 16              241
 22              232
 28              213
 34              324
 40              333
 46              441
 52              431
 58              413
```

Then take one observation at random from each of the selected combinations. (Ask another question if you'd like a simple sampling algorithm.)

In this sample, you can see that A = 1 appears twice; A = 2, three times; A = 3 twice; and A = 4 three times.

One problem with systematic sampling is the inconvenience when the list size  is not a multiple of the sample size. There are procedures for dealing with this (L Kish, 1965, Survey Sampling), which may be consulted.

The frequency of missing combinations would be reduced if the sampling was done with 3 zones, but this solution must be rejected. There would be 27 combinations.  Three different systematic samples of size nine exist (An additional combination would be chosen at random).  However one of the possible systematic samples excludes C = 1 and C = 3. For three zone criteria, the triple lattice approach is superior.

2. Random 3 x 3 x 3 Cubic  Lattices

Divide A, B, and C, into three zones each. There will be $3^3 = 27$ zone combinations.

General lattice sampling is covered in Chapter 11 of  RJ Jesson, 1978, Statistical Survey Techniques, Wiley, NY.

A  balanced cubic sampling lattice is a 3 x 3 x 3 cube,  with three  ABC combination entries, situated so that there is one entry in every zone of A, B, and C.  Here's an example of a canonical lattice, in which the nonzero entries are at the diagonal combinations 111 222 and 333. I omit the zeros for simplicity.  Since I can't show three dimensions, I indicate the layer A zone in brackets []. In practice, I'd remove the brackets, just showing the A values as the table entries.

```
             C
       1     2    3
 B
 1    [1]
 2          [2]
 3               [3]
```

where [.] indicates the  A layer. Notice this important property: there is exactly one entry in each row, column, and layer. Thus the combinations in this lattice are balanced on all zones. We start with this initial lattice, and  apply in succession  random permutations of rows and columns, and layers.  The resulting lattices will maintain the balance property. As there are six possible permutations of three items, the number of possible lattices is $6^3= 216$.

2.1. randomize rows (B).  Say the permutation is 2 1 3, meaning that   the first row becomes the second, and the third remains the same. The result is:

```
               C
           1     2     3
 B
 1              [2]
 2        [1]
 3                    [3]
```

2.2 Now Randomize columns; say the order is 3 2 1.

```
              C
 B
         1    2     3
 1           [2]
 2                 [1]
 3      [3]
```

2.3. Now randomly permute the A layers.  Say this permutation is 1 3 2, meaning [1]->[1] , and [3] and [2] switch.

```
  The resulting table is:
              C
         1    2     3
 B
 1           [3]
 2                 [1]
 3      [2]
```

From this, we can read off the ABC locations of the selected points. Recall that the number in brackets is the permuted A value. The location in the first row is 312 (A = 3 in brackets, B =1 , C = 2);  the location in the second is 123, and that in the third is 231.

Repeat this process two more times, and you will have selected nine locations from the stratum, three in each zone of A, B, and C. (Remove the brackets for ease of writing).  To make n = 10, add a location; 222 is a plausible choice, if it's not already taken. Then draw one observation from each location.

Choosing a permutation: there are only six permutations of the numbers (123, 132, 213, 232, 312, 313).  Put them into a small data set; and repeatedly sort by  a new random number.  Owners of classic texts in experimental design may find tables of random permutations in the appendices.

Comment: There may also be some room for balanced sampling, see Tille, Y (2006). Sampling Algorithms, Springer, NY.

Comment: Many or all of the algorithms in the book  appear in Tille's Sampling package in R.

Comment: @SteveSamuels Thank you very much for the very detailed explanations of the two approaches.