# Sampling and design problem

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, sample

Suppose there are quite many (hundreds/thousands) variables, $X_1$,...,$X_m$, in a computer model, following some multivariate distribution. How can we get a sample of these variables that has good coverage of the possible values while the sample size is not large saying 100-500?

In addition, if a low-dimensional transformation is applied to these variables saying $Z_1=T_1X$,...,$Z_d=T_dX$, where $X=(X_1,...,X_N)'$ and $d<<m$. If there is a way to sample or make design on the low-dimensional space $(Z_1,...Z_d)$ so that a moderate size of samples on $(Z_1,...Z_d)$ can cover the possible values well. I know Latin Hypercube Design is often used in computer experiment, but here the transformed variables $Z_1$,...$Z_d$ are not independent that the domain of these values are not a hypercube... Would anyone have experience or any thoughts or references on this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the transformation is PCA, then the $Z$ values will be independent, that might be a solution?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama They are not in a regular shape though... $X$'s are correlated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a *hierarchic serpentine sort* of the $Z$'s, followed by a systematic sample.   A serpentine sort on the Z's assures that neighboring observations are closer together than they would be with a standard sort. The systematic sample will ensure that the entire sorted list is covered.

A hierarchic serpentine sort was formally defined in  Williams, Rick L, and James R Chromy. 1980. SAS sample selection macros. Proceedings of the Fifth Annual SAS Users Group International Conference 5, 392-396. http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI80/Sugi-80-71%20Williams%20Chromy.pdf.

A simple three-variable example is shown in [Sub-population of large dataset based on multiple criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184306/sub-population-of-large-dataset-based-on-multiple-criteria/185082#185082).

PROC SURVEYSELECT in SAS can do the sort described by Williams and Chromy and will take the systematic sample. See p. 8484 of the procedure manual chapter (http://www.math.wpi.edu/saspdf/stat/chap63.pdf).

A SAS macro by Barbara Lepidus Carlson and Linda Bandeh does serpentine sorting. I don't have a SAS installation, so haven't tried it, but the logic is explained in some detail.  See p.1090 of http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI95/Sugi-95-182%20Carlson%20Cox%20Bandeh.pdf.